# How can i give grant access to specific user-role for a frquently dropped and created table in Vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table which is frequently dropped and created with the same name in a schema. How can i create grant access to a user-role when the table is created in Vertica?

P.S: This question is specifc to vertica, but all ideas are welcome. Also dropping is business requirement and we cannot even truncate the table and clear data out.

Comment: Why not automate it?

Comment: Tell the business folks to keep their requirements out of the technical arena. :-)  I have trouble imagining why `TRUNCATE TABLE` would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Vertica does not support a fixed role that can run a SELECT statement against any table or view in the database(SQL Server db_datareader roles for example).
  So depending on how you create the object(DBA creation,workflow or any ETL tool), you need to automate this. 
 You can create a UDP to do this for you and just call the UDP in your job,script,workflow.
 Also you can create a UDP to extract the actual grants,access to the object and also stores it in a temp file to be executed after object recreation.

But the question is ? is recreating the table needed ? What is the use of this ? Maybe there is a better solution ! 
And @Kermit you gotta stop down voting !

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it in steps when you recreate the table.

1) Generate the GRANT script based on the existing grants.  (You'll need to change this to match how you handle grants)

```
select 'GRANT ' || privileges_description || ' ON ' || object_schema || '.' || object_name || ' TO ' || grantee || ';' from grants
where object_schema = 'MYSCHEMA' object_name = 'MYTABLE'
and grantee ilike 'role%';
```

2) Create the new table like the old one (be sure to save your projections!)

```
CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.NEW_MYTABLE LIKE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE INCLUDING PROJECTIONS;
```

3) Drop old table

```
DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE;
```

4) Rename new table

```
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.NEW_MYTABLE RENAME TO MYTABLE;
```

5) Apply generated grants

```
GRANT ROLE_MYROLE TO MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE;
```